# Can I set memory limits on cpanel acounts

Tags: apache, cpanel, vps, whm, memory

I have one account on my vps that is hogging more than it's fair share of memory.  How can I limit that account's memory usage?

- Setting `memory_limit` in the *php.ini*?  It appears as if this sets the
  memory per script – so that would change based on the number of pages
  or requests instead of the total for the account?
- Setting the `RLimitMEM` in Apache sets a new memory limit for Apache
  processes.  (in whm (Home >> Service Configuration >> Apache
  Configuration >> Memory Usage Restrictions)  That would also change
  the total memory based on requests instead of the total for the
  account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only memory limitations currently supported are the ones that you have asked about. There is no way currently in cPanel to apply a memory limit on an account basis, only on a per script or per process basis. The issue you would encounter is how to apply a memory limit on a per account basis as each account does not spawn its own Apache process and if it did would be a waste of resources as the account would not always need that process to be active. If you are seeing performance issues try applying a per-scriipt php.ini memory limitation.